# External screen detected but not working

Tags: nvidia, display, dell, hdmi, 19.04

I just installed Ubuntu 19.04 on my Dell Precision 5530 (dual boot with Win10) it works fine if not for the Nvidia Quadro P2000 (Suspend/Resume problems...).

I have a problem with my external display (27" - 4k iiyama). Dual screen works fine on Windows, it worked fine on Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10 but on my Ubuntu 19.04 fresh install the second screen is detected (showed in screens settings) but there is a "No signal detected" message on the screen.

**What I tried :**

- Disabled TLP
- Changed HDMI cable / turned off and on screen and computer multiple times
- Switched resolutions for both screens from 4k to 1080p and from 4k to 720p
- Switched from intel to nvidia (was on intel because of suspend/resume problems and for battery saving)
- Tried different drivers (Nvidia 390, 415, 430, 418, xorg)

I got it to work for like 5 minutes by switching to 720p and then settings both screens to 4k again but after restart it doesn't work anymore.

Any idea ?